# how to test ng-form item validity with jasmine in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I try to unit test an angularjs directive with jasmine.
My directive consists to complete, on blur event an id with leading zeroes and then check if this id already exists in a list of id (provided by a json file).
how to test the validity of the form (id.$error.unique)
thanks in advance for help !

the directive :

```
angular.module('bdd.directives').directive('bddUnique', function () {
    function formatIdentifier(id) {
        if (id) {
            var zeroes = '0000000000';
            var formattedId = zeroes.substring(0, zeroes.length - id.length) + id;
            return formattedId;
        }
        return '';
    }

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',

        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.bind('blur', function (e) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('unique', true);

                if (ctrl && element.val()) {

                    var identifiers = scope.$eval(attrs.bddUnique);
                    var currentValue = formatIdentifier(element.val());

                    ctrl.$setViewValue(currentValue);
                    ctrl.$render();
                    var idFound = _.find(identifiers, {
                        id : currentValue
                    });

                    if (idFound !== undefined) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('unique', false);
                    }
                }
                scope.$apply();
            });

        }
    }
});
```

the unit test

```
describe('uniqueDirective', function () {
    var mockCompile, mockScope;

    var changeInputValue;

    var htmlFragment = '<div ng-form name="myForm"><input type="text" ng-model="id" bdd-unique="identifiers"/>';
    htmlFragment += '<p id="errorMsg" ng-show="myForm.numero.$invalid">identifier already exist</p></div>';

    // / / / / load the myModule.directives module, which contains the directive
    beforeEach(module('myModule', function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('resolver', {
            identifiers : function () {
                return readJSON('app/assets/mocks/identifiers.json');
            }
        });
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, resolver) {
        mockCompile = _$compile_;
        mockScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        mockScope.identifiers = resolver.identifiers();

         elem = angular.element(htmlFragment);
         template = mockCompile(elem)(mockScope);
         mockScope.$digest(); 

    }));

    it('id already exists', function () {


        var input = template.find('input'); 
        input.val('15);
        input.triggerHandler('blur');


        expect(mockScope.id).toBe('0000000015'); // OK
        // expect(myForm.numero.$error.unique.$valid).toBeFalsy();  //how to specify ???

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Add name="numero' to htmlFragment, so it becomes

```
 var htmlFragment = '<div ng-form name="myForm"><input type="text" 
    name='numero' ng-model="id" bdd-unique="identifiers"/>';
```

then to test error case

```
var form = mockScope.myForm;
expect(form.numero.$error.unique).toBeTruthy();
```

to test normal case

```
var form = mockScope.myForm;
expect(form.numero.$error.unique).toBeUndefined();
```